# Desktop App Toast Notifications OnActivated not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, toast

I've been following the steps from this Microsoft guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop), and I'm using the same project from their github and the toasts show but the OnActivated method is not firing and my actual project is a WPF application and the toast notifications display properly but again no firing of the OnActivated method in App.xmal.cs.

Has anyone else had this issue before? I feel like it has something to do with the com server not activating correctly but it's hard to test when even the Microsoft project doesn't work for me.

I believe it's something to do with

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your binding template in your notification is set to "ToastGeneric". Other templates are for old style toasts and only triggers OnLaunched()

Example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toast launch="{&quot;Url&quot; : &quot;http://cnn.com&quot;}">

<visual><binding template="ToastGeneric">
<text hint-maxLines="1">Adaptive Tiles Meeting</text>
    <text>Conf Room 2001 / Building 135</text>
    <text>10:00 AM - 10:30 AM</text>
<image placement="hero" src="https://picsum.photos/364/180?image=1043"/>
</binding>
</visual>
</toast>
```